# ¿Cómo solucionar error 303 de un fetch js en framework Codeigniter 4?

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

Estoy tratando de hacer un pequeño programa de inventario. Los productos los quiero añadir con un formulario en un modal, pero a la hora de enviar los datos del formulario vía fetch a mi backend hecho con Codeigniter 4, solo me llega un error 303 a pesar de que la dirección esta correcta¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error 303 y qué me lleguen los datos al backend?

**Sé que sería mucho más fácil simplemente capturar los datos directamente en el backend, pero quiero repartir la tarea con el frontend para más adelante hacer cosas con esos datos.**

---

**Screenshot del header**

### [image: Screenshot del header]
[image: Screenshot del header2]
[image: Screenshot del header3]

**Código formulario**

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo route_to('addProduct') ?>" id="formAddProduct">
      <div class="mb-3">
         <label for="InputNameProduct" class="form-label">Nombre del Producto</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputNameProduct" aria-describedby="nameProduct">
         <div id="nameProduct" class="form-text">Nombre inválido</div>
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
         <label for="InputSKUProduct" class="form-label">SKU</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputSKUProduct" aria-describedby="SKUProduct">
         <div id="SKUProduct" class="form-text">SKU inválido</div>
       </div>
       <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="InputCatProduct" class="form-label">Categoría</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputCatProduct" aria-describedby="CatProduct">
          <div id="CatProduct" class="form-text">Categoría inválida</div>
       </div>
       <div class="mb-3">
          <textarea name="descripProduct" id="InputDescripProduct" cols="60" rows="5" aria-describedby="DescripProduct" placeholder="Descripción"></textarea>
          <div id="DescripProduct" class="form-text">Descripción inválida</div>
       </div>
       <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="InputPrecioProduct" class="form-label">Precio</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="InputPrecioProduct" aria-describedby="PrecioProduct">
          <div id="PrecioProduct" class="form-text">Precio inválido</div>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
       </div>
```

---

**Rutas relacionadas**

```
$routes->group('inventario', function ($routes) {
    $routes->get('/', 'InventarioController::index',['as'=>'indexInventario']);
    $routes->post('addProduct','InventarioController::addProduct');
    $routes->get('addProduct','InventarioController::addProduct',['as' => 'addProduct']);
});
```

---

**Código JS**

```
//Asignación de variables
var formAddProduct = document.getElementById("formAddProduct");
var InputNameProduct = document.getElementById("InputNameProduct");
var InputSKUProduct = document.getElementById("InputSKUProduct");
var InputCatProduct = document.getElementById("InputCatProduct");
var InputDescripProduct = document.getElementById("InputDescripProduct");
var InputPrecioProduct = document.getElementById("InputPrecioProduct");

//Toda la programación del JS va dentro de este evento load
window.addEventListener('load',(e)=>{
    //Evento submit para el formulario de addProduct
    formAddProduct.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();
        //Se añaden todos los input en este array...
        var data = {
            nameProduct:    InputNameProduct.value,
            skuProduct:     InputSKUProduct.value,
            catProduct:     InputCatProduct.value,
            descripProduct: InputDescripProduct.value,
            precioProduct:  InputPrecioProduct.value,
        }
        console.log(data);
        var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        //...y se envían por este fetch
        fetch('/inventario/addProduct', {
            method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
            body:  dataJSON,// data can be `string` or {object}!
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
          }).then(res => res.text()
          )
          .catch(error => console.log('Error:', error))
          .then(text => console.log(text));
    });
});
```

---

**Código correspondiente en ProductController.php**

```
public function addProduct(){
        $data = [];
        $datos = json_decode($this->request->getPost($data));
        json_encode("ok");
}
```

---

**Código correspondiente en la vista de addProduct.php**
<?php

```
$data = [];
$datos = json_decode($this->request->getPost($data), true);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($datos);
echo "</pre>";
json_encode("ok");
```

---

Comment: Y tu pregunta es?

Comment: @Arriel ¿Cómo puedo solucionar el error 303 y qué me lleguen los datos al backend?

Comment: Será un problema de ambigüedad? Tienes un get y un post en la misma ruta /addProduct. Por qué? Si vas a crear un nuevo objeto, debe ser a través de POST, semánticamente es lo correcto, y es también más seguro.

Comment: @Arriel pues no, de hecho lo tenía en un principio sin esa ruta GET, pero aún así me lanzaba el mismo error. Se la volví a borrar por si acaso.

Comment: Por favor muéstranos el código del método `addProduct`

Comment: @Arriel actualizado.

Comment: fijate si no es que necesitas hacer un return o print/echo del `json_encode` que sería la "respuesta"; agrega un `die;` o `exit();` para cortar/ir viendo hasta donde llega y pq es que luego "redirecciona" ( 303 es ok si hice lo q me pediste pero fijate en este otro lado, puede que haya un redirect al root/default   )

Comment: @aloMalbarez acabo de encontrar el problema, lo publico de inmediato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente después de horas buscando, encontré que el problema estaba en el archivo filters.php en la carpeta config. Tenía activado el CSRF y eso provocaba el redireccionamiento

Comment: podes capturar el csfr y enviarlo en el ajax https://stackoverflow.com/a/10794847/1423096